# Al consultar la función me da el resultado en "null" como soluciono para que no me de null

Tags: sql-server

```
 create function calcula_subtotal (id integer,cantidad integer)
          returns int
          deterministic
          begin
             declare precio int;
             set precio = (select Precio from tbl_libros where isbn= id);
             return precio * cantidad;
          end//
```

Comment: Pues, si el select no encuentra registros, da null. Ahí ya sería usar ISNULL y dar un valor por defecto (cero?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La creación de la función como tal, está equivocada, modifícala y trata así:

```sql
create function calcula_subtotal(@id int, @cantidad int)
returns int as 
          -- deterministic
BEGIN
          declare @precio int
             set @precio = (select Precio from tbl_libros where isbn= @id);
             return @precio * @cantidad
END
```

Luego:

```sql
select dbo.calcula_subtotal(111,2) RETORNO
```

El resultado sería:

| Resultado |
| --- |
| 48 |

> El DBFiddle para que lo veas detalladamente: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce90b970ea2441e9ca0e5a4ce2e3ff11

Comment: es lo mismo si estoy utilizando command line??

Comment: No es lo mismo, pero tengo entendido que puedes activar la sintaxis de T-SQL en el command line (o ciertas partes de la sintaxis, no estoy bien ilustrado acerca de ese tema en específico).

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda